# Convert Roman Numerals to decimal numbers in C

Tags: c

This is part of a code in C to convert Roman Numerals to decimal numbers. But I can't really understand what exactly it does. Can someone give me a description?

```
if ((strlen(roman_Number) - i) > 2) {
    if (digitValue(roman_Number[i]) < digitValue(roman_Number[i + 2])) {
        printf("Invalid roman number");
        return 0;
    }
}
if (digitValue(roman_Number[i]) >= digitValue(roman_Number[i + 1]))
    number = number + digitValue(roman_Number[i]);
else {
    number = number + (digitValue(roman_Number[i + 1]) - digitValue(roman_Number[i]));
    i++;
}
i++;

} // unbalanced bracket
```

Comment: roman_Number should be an array containing the numbers, digitValue() does the magic. Sure you don't just want us to solve your homework?

Comment: @user349821 How about [Something like This](http://ideone.com/s5I50U)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are at least 3 letters starting at offset `i`, and the third has a value larger than the first, the roman number is invalid.

If the value of the letter is less than the value of the next letter, subtract the value of the first from the value of the second, add this to the total and skip both.

Otherwise, add the value of the current letter to the total.

These statements should be inside the body of a `for` loop that iterates `i` from `0` to the length of the string `roman_Number`.